# Gradle ignores dependency

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My module dependency looks like this:

```
dependencies {
compile project (':module1')
compile project(':module2')
compile project(':module3')
}
```

When Gradle is executing it compiles modules 1 & 2 but skips 3. 
Then build fails since some classes are missing.

Answer (score 0):

What dependencies you specify has nothing to do with what modules Gradle will build, in a multi-module project.

This has to be part of a multi-module build, with a "settings.gradle" that specifies all of the modules that are part of the build.  I'm guessing you must have that, partially, because you say that it builds module1 and module2.  Perhaps module3 isn't in the settings.gradle file?

Comment: my settings.gradle includes all the modules
I am trying to add this a module to my project
From some reason dependency 3 doesn't compile
It does compile as the dependency of other modules but not for this one.

Comment: No idea then, with the information you've given here. We would have to see your entire build structure, including the settings.gradle file.